# Elasticsearch-net & NEST - Search Response is different when sorting

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

```
...
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
        {
            Size = 100,
            Source = sf,
            Filter = filters,
            Sort = sortsFields
        };

var searchResponse = client.Search<dynamic>(searchRequest);
```

NEST does not return the correct sorted SearchResponse from all the shards when sorting
is used.

Turn on ES slowlog to see the queries from all the shards in elasticsearch.yml and execute the same
query w/ sense. The result is totally out of order.

- index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 5ms
- index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 5ms
- index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 5ms
- index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 5ms

Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: could you provide an  example query i.e listing sort fields and difference in result  from sense and nest ?

Answer (score 0):

Good news...I fixed the problem simply by specifying my index.

```
this.settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                node,
                "x-event-*"
            );

this.client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

When sorting without specifying any default index or Indices in your SearchRequest, the sorting result is not correct.